# R: How to recode binary factor levels (0=0, 1=1) in BASE R

Tags: r, refactoring

When I read in a csv file, there's a binary target.

as.factor is assigning the 0's and 1's backwards (index wise).

I want 0='0' and 1 = '1'

I found the function Recode in the Car package (or maybe it was dplyr), and another one in Tidyverse.  Both of those packages conflict with other packages and break my R code.

How do I recode the binary factor levels in BASE r?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with backwards? Could you give an elaboration/explanation. Also you do not have to load the whole package. Just use the specific function you need by using the resolution operator

Comment: Backwards index-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify the `levels` and the corresponding `labels` in `factor`.

```
df1$col1 <- factor(df1$col1, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c('0', '1'))
```

In this way, it can be changed to any order

```
factor(df1$col1, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c('1', '0'))
```

Or

```
factor(df1$col1, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c('2', '1'))
```

Comment: Thank you.  BTW, you have to use it in an assignment; df1$col1 <- factor(df1$col1, ...

Comment: @Larry Yes, it is already updated in the first code block.

Comment: Well, I thought this was my problem with having to use "Output4$net.result[,2])"  -- with the neuralnet function/package.  I have to use [,2] to get the second field.  Output$net.result are all reversed otherwise.  -- But this problem remains.

Comment: @Larry It depends on your object.  Is it a `data.frame` or `matrix` (`matrix` cannot hold these factor attributes)

Comment: It's a dataframe.

Comment: @Larry may be your `net.result` column is not a `vector`.  Please check the `str(Output4)`